# Корректировка sql запроса

Tags: sql

Получил на собеседовании задание по sql:

> Получить имя и количество раз, сколько оно повторялось, но вывести
>   только те имена, которые повторялись больше 2-х раз - сортировка по
>   количеству повторений, от большего до меньшего.

Моим решением было:

```
select name, count(name)
from table
group by name
having count(name) > 2
order by count(name) desc;
```

фидбек интервьюера был таким: запрос **"почти" правильный**.

Может кто-то подсказать, как его надо поменять или улучшить?

Comment: Всё правильно в ответе. "Улучшения" которые в ответах описали не существенны. Если ваш потенциальный работодатель придирается к таким вещам - не советую идти под его начало.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ORDER BY` выполняется после `SELECT`, поэтому `count(name)` в нем ИМХО лишний:

```
select name, count(name) AS num
from table
group by name
having count(name) > 2
order by num desc;
```

Кроме того безымянное поле `count(name)` выглядит не очень красиво. Может быть еще и поэтому **"почти" правильно**?

Comment: Фраза **почти правильно** странная - результат будет получен правильный, остальное уже красивости.

Comment: @Denis, это из вопроса, кто знает что интервьюер считает "почти" правильным

Comment: @Mirdin Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Ага, а ещё можно upper(name) в group by добавить, вдруг collation чувствителен к регистру, обрезание начальных пробелов, удаление "шумов" из name перед группировкой и ещё много чего. Ещё форматирование могло не понравится или то, что ключевые слова в нижнем регистре. Всё это несущественно.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написал так, чтобы не вычислять три раза `count`

```
select name, count(name)
from table
group by name
having count(name) > 2
order by 2 desc;
```

Или через алиасы

```
select name, count(name) cnt
from table
group by name
having count(name) > 2
order by cnt desc;
```

Comment: тогда и having count(name) > 2 можно на having count(cnt) > 2 заменить

Comment: @koks_rs, нет нельзя, having выполняется до селекта

Comment: @Mirdin, нельзя потому что производительность уменьшится или ошибка ?

Comment: @koks_rs, ошибка -- cnt в этот момент еще не существует

Comment: @Mirdin, странно у меня в mysql все работает,  и на пол миллиона строк разница во времени  в пределах погрешности

Comment: @koks_rs, по стандарту должна быть ошибка, (в MSSQL - она кстати есть), а вот в MySQL, не знаю, я в ней почти не работал.